# plug react lint rule to custom hook

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I have implemented a custom useEffect hook in react (let's say named useEffectCustom), and I would like the react lint rules to be applied to my custom hook.
For instance:

```
[count, setCount] = useState(0);

// There is a warning fired by the linter here (missing dependencies: count and setCount)
useEffect(() => setCount(count+1), [])

// I would like this piece of code fires a warning as well!
useEffectCustom(() => setCount(count+1), [])
```

Does anyone know how to tell eslint to apply the same rule as useEffect on my custom hook?

NB: I'm not using CRA, I can modify almost anything I want in my project!

Comment: why not just ignore the lint error?

Comment: @RedBaron He's not encountering any error, he wants others to encounter errors for his custom hook.